# Residue formula if $\lim_{z\to \infty} z^a f(z)=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

> $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $\{Im(z)\leq0 \}\subset\Omega$ is a holomorphic function. Suppose that $\lim_{z\to \infty} z^a f(z)=0$ for every $a>1$.
>
> Prove that $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(t)dt=2i\pi\sum$ the residues of $f$ in the lower half of the plane.

(1) One of the conditions looks similar to $\lim_{z\to 0} z^a f(z)=0$ which would indicate $0$ is a pole of order $a$. But in the problem, is not quite the same thing.

(1) It might be useful to use $\displaystyle \int_{-R}^R f(t)dt$ and then take $R\to \infty$, but how to get the residues involved in the proof?

(2) If I consider the upper half of semicircle of radius $R$ (denote it $S$) then I could say by means of the residue theorem that $\displaystyle \int _S f = 2\pi \sum R_i$, where $R_i$ are the residues of the poles inside the semicircle.

(3) The semicircle could be separated in the line $[-R,R]$ and the arc $\gamma$, which I think would be given by $\gamma=Re^{it}$, with $t\in[0,\pi]$, then $d\gamma=iRe^{it}dt$. Then

$$\int_S f = \int_{-R}^R f + \int_\gamma f=2\pi i\sum R_i\\  \int_{-R}^R = 2\pi i \sum R_i - i\int_0^\pi f(Re^{it})(iRe^{it})dt $$

(4) Now it should be

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}=2\pi i \sum R_i -  \lim_{R\to \infty} i\int_0^\pi f(Re^{it})(iRe^{it})dt= 2\pi i \sum R_i +  \lim_{R\to \infty} \int_0^\pi f(Re^{it})(Re^{it})dt$$

(5) Here the condition $\lim_{z\to \infty} z^af(z)=0$ should come into play... except it doesn't. It doesn't because it is valid for $a>1$, while I have exactly $zf(z)$ so the integral doesn't vanish. That is where I'm stuck with the problem

Comment: All you need^, with $C_R$ the rectangle $R \to -R \to -R-iR \to -R+iR \to R$ is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{C_{R_n}} f(z)dz = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(z)dz$ for some sequence $R_n \to \infty$, so you can apply the residue theorem to the LHS. Try with $f(z) = \frac{(z+1)^{-2}}{e^{2i \pi (z+1)}-1}$, $R_n = n+1/2$.

Comment: @reuns Shouldn't be $R-iR$ instead of $-R+iR$?

Comment: Sure. Did you look at $f(z) = \frac{(z+1)^{-2}}{e^{2i \pi (z+1)}-1}$ ? It has infinitely many poles so you need to take a sequence such that the contour passes in the middle of two poles. With $\lim_{|z|\to \infty} z^af(z)=0$ implicitely $f$ has only finitely many poles.